# How to get the current dialog stack from the bot framework's botbuilder (JavaScript)?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am building a chat bot with BotBuilder (Node version).
I wish to print out the dialog stack for debug purpose.
Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer to my own question.

After research on the source code, I found that we can print the call stack of a session by:

```
console.log(session.dialogStack());
// or
console.log(session.sessionState.callstack);
```

Comment: You could use `session.dialogStack();`